# Laravel + Nginx + Basic Auth: how to leave some routes unprotected?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, http-authentication

We have Nginx and using it to serve a Laravel 8 project

I have the need  to protect with a basic auth this demo project.

it works, using nginx and auth_basic_file directive

```
auth_basic            "My DEMO";

location ~ ^/(api|public|images)/.* {
    auth_basic off;
    try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}



location ~ \.php$ {

    # Protect access
    auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/auth/.htpasswd;

    add_header      X-Dovesono-php 1;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

### My Goal

I need to leave un protected entire block of /api/<some thing

### The problem

Actually, using the above config, the browser ask me to authenticate at every ajax call to /api/.
Also, even inserting right username and password, it will reask indefinitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved using this:

```
server {
   ....
   auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/auth/.htpasswd;

  location / {
    auth_basic   "My DEMO";
    try_files    $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    ... ...
  }

  location /api/ {
    auth_basic   off;
    try_files    $uri /index.php?$query_string;
  }

}
```

If first matches `/api/`, no auth set up, and then causes the restart of parsing that will ending using `location ~ \.php$`.

So page is served, but without asking http basic auth

For every other routes, it apply auth_basic and then causes the restart of parsing that will ending using `location ~ \.php$`

So page is served, but asking http basic auth